PyTorch model running on CPU despite MPS (Apple Silicon) being available and detected
I'm trying to run a HuggingFace Transformers model on my Apple Silicon Mac using MPS (Metal Performance Shaders), but despite MPS being available and detected, the model keeps running on CPU, causing significant performance issues.
Here's my model initialization code:
def instantiate_model(cfg: dict):
    model_fp = cfg['model']['model_fp']
    batch_size = cfg['model']['batch_size']
    default_threshold = float(cfg['postprocessing']['threshold'])

    # Clear any cached memory
    torch.mps.empty_cache()
    
    # Set device
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
        device = torch.device("mps")
        print(f"MPS device found: {device}")
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")
        print(f"MPS not available, using: {device}")

    # Load model
    model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
        model_fp,
        torch_dtype=torch.float32
    )
    model.eval()
    model = model.to(device)

    # Training arguments setup
    args = TrainingArguments(
        model_fp,
        learning_rate=3e-5,
        per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        evaluation_strategy=IntervalStrategy.STEPS,
        eval_steps=100,
        max_steps=4000,
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        metric_for_best_model='f1',
        save_total_limit=5,
        no_cuda=True,
        use_mps_device=torch.backends.mps.is_available()
    )

    trainer = MultiLabelTrainer(model, args)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_fp)

    return {'trainer': trainer, 'tokenizer': tokenizer, 'default_threshold': default_threshold}

The code correctly detects MPS and prints "MPS device found: mps", but monitoring my system shows that the processing is still happening on CPU.
Environment details:
macOS on Apple Silicon (M2)
Python 3.10
PyTorch with MPS support installed
transformers library latest version
What I've tried:
Explicitly setting device to
Confirming MPS availability with torch.backends.mps.is_available()
Moving the model to device using model.to(device)
Setting use_mps_device=True in TrainingArguments
How can I ensure the model actually runs on MPS instead of CPU?

Explicitly setting device to 'mps':
python
device = torch.device("mps")
model = model.to(device)


Verifying MPS is actually available:
pythonCopyprint(f"Is MPS available? {torch.backends.mps.is_available()}")
print(f"Is MPS built? {torch.backends.mps.is_built()}")

Output shows both are True

Checking model device after moving it:
pythonCopyprint(f"Model device: {next(model.parameters()).device}")

Output shows 'mps'


Monitoring CPU usage during model execution shows 600% CPU utilization (and almost 0% GPU usage), suggesting the model isn't utilizing the GPU despite being moved to the MPS device
Setting use_mps_device=True in TrainingArguments
Expected behavior:
The model should utilize the Apple Silicon GPU via MPS
CPU usage should be lower as computation is offloaded to GPU
Processing should be significantly faster compared to CPU execution
Actual behavior:
Despite MPS being detected and the model being moved to the MPS device
CPU usage remains at 100% during model execution
Processing speed is the same as CPU-only execution
The system is becoming overloaded due to CPU processing
